# Can't log in via ssh from new user

Tags: ssh, sshd

Let's say that user **A** is my main user.

I configured **A** to work with ssh and I maniged to connect to it via localhost or my ip.

I want to create a user who is not in the sudo group and has permissions to only certain folders so I made one with adduser.

After that I did the exact same steps I did for the **A** dmin user.

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
sudo cat /path/to/new/user's/id_dsa.pub >> /path/to/Admin/user's/authorized_keys
sudo service ssh restart
```

I cloud not connect to localhost (or anything else.) I deleted **A** private key and did the same steps again. It again worked for **A** but not for the other user. I also repeaded the same stepps for the user **postgres** and I had the same outcome.

The error I keep getting is:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Extra information:
In the ssh config the new user is allowed to connect (`AllowUsers`)
The owner of the new user's `.ssh` is the new user.

**edit**: what i get in the auth log

```
sshd[20341]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

I am running out of ideas. Any suggestions ?

EDIT: I found the problem. I was putting the authorized_keys in another user's authorized_key's file.
what I was doing would enable me from remote user b to log in as user A. What I was trying to do was connect from remote user b to local user b.

Comment: Check the auth log for additional info - /var/log/auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some clarifications, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. What I understood from your post was that

- You have 2 users : "admin" and "b"
- You refer to "admin" as "A" in your question
- You want to be able to connect to the admin account, using ssh, from the b account

So the command you are trying to run is this one?

```
[b@computer]$ ssh admin@localhost
```

Am I correctly understanding ?

---

I'm not sure I got this right, but as asked, form my understanding:

- `computer-1` has two users, *admin* and *b*
- OP wanted `[b@computer-1]$ ssh b@localhost` to work
- Instead made `[b@computer-1]$ ssh admin@localhost` work

(copied b's public key to the wrong user's authorized_keys)

Comment: I have figured it out and explained problem. Since there is no point in leaving this question opened I will select your answer as the 'answer'. It will be nice if you elaborate a bit more on my answer so if someone else finds this it can be better readable.